# Codigo mudo no iframe

Tags: iframe

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor, quero colocar esse *iframe* no meu site, mas quero que ele de *play* em *mute*, tem algum código pra colocar dentro do *iframe* pra ele ficar mudo?

alguém me explica como faço?

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="320" height="180" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/IDVIDEO" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player), você pode passar um parâmetro `mute` pra ele, aonde 0 não é mudo e 1 é mudo:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270"
src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/IDVIDEO?mute=1"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Valeu bro, e caso eu quisesse usar ?autoplay=1 como faria? ou não tem como usar os dois juntos?

Comment: @KaioS só passar mais um parâmetro: `www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/IDVIDEO?mute=1&autoplay=1`

Comment: valeu Artur, funcionou aqui bro, suave :)